# RecyclerView - No focus on new item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I use the recyclerview and an item consists of an EditText. At the beginning there is one item. If I insert some text to the EditText I use the afterChange() TextWatcher to create a new item on the RecyclerView Adapter.
So far it works quite fine. But I focus the next element after creating it in the onBindViewHolder() method of my adapter.

This works quite fine but not if an item is added which is theoretically behind the keyboard (the keyboard is always open while this process because at any time an EditText is focused). For any item added above the keyboard it works, if it is added visually "under" the keyboard the item is not focused and the focus remains on the item where the text is inserted.
How can I fix it?